# nginx max upload size elasticbeanstalk aws

Tags: nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

i have a probleme whene i want to maximize upload size with nginx on elasticbeanstalk aws, i created
a file .platform/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf :

```
client_max_body_size 100M;
```

then i commited and eb deploy
it works for a while and i could uploade files with big sizes with my dashboard
but after a period (10 --> 15 min ) an error in the log comes after any request

```
21311#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: ***.**.**.***, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/", host: "***.**.**.**"
```

any suggestions to solve this probleme!!

Comment: Is your app working on EB? Maybe it crashed as it seems nginx lost connection to it.

Comment: the app is working and runs successfully...but when i want to connect with my dashboard to the server or do anything else i recive tha error 21311#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: ***.**.**.***, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/", host: "***.**.**.**"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for anyone who have the same probleme ..
the solution that i found is to put the .conf file in

.platform\nginx\conf.d\elasticbeanstalk/proxy.conf

with content

```
client_max_body_size 1G; 
proxy_buffering off; 
proxy_request_buffering off;
```

it worked for me

Comment: Thanks it worked for me. I just had to move the .conf file to .platform\nginx\conf.d\elasticbeanstalk/

Answer (score 0):

What is your running app in 127.0.0.1:8080 ? It looks like the app in port of 8080 time out or over the max upload size .